# Lambda expression with two objects

Tags: c#, lambda

I know that this can be rewritten using a lambda expression. But I cant seem to figure it out. does anyone have an opinion on how it should be written using a lambda.

```
            foreach (var _systemItem in _systemData)
            {
                foreach (var _institutionItem in _institutionData)
                {
                    if (_systemItem.LookupValue == _institutionItem.OriginalSystemLookupValue)
                    {
                        _values.Add(new LookupValue()
                        {
                            DisplayText = _institutionItem.LookupText,
                            Value = _institutionItem.LookupValue
                        });
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        _values.Add(new LookupValue()
                        {
                            DisplayText = _systemItem.LookupText,
                            Value = _systemItem.LookupValue
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Your code is essentially creating a value list containing the cross-product of your system and institution lists. So if _systemData contains 5 elements and _institutionData contains 10 elements, your _values list will end up with 50 elements. Is that really what you want?

Comment: No I am not..basically if i have a system list of states containing all 50..and for instance an institution wants say Alaska spelled in all caps ALASKA. I would want ALASKA to replace Alaksa. So we still have 50 items but one replaces the other. I have a field in the db that stores the original value that im doing the compare of..if there is a match then take the institution not the system..hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, I have an opinion.  I'd write it like this:

```
var pairs = _systemData.SelectMany(s =>
    _institutionData.Select(i => new { System = s, Institution = i }));

_values.AddRange(pairs.Select(x =>
{
    bool match = x.System.LookupValue == x.Insitution.OriginalSystemLookupValue;

    return match ? new LookupValue(x.Institution) : new LookupValue(x.System);
}));
```

And move the object initializers for `LookupValue` into real constructors that take an `Institution` or `System`.

Comment: after a bit of tinkering this worked perfectly. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4):

Like this:

```
values.AddRange(from s in _systemData
                from i in institutionData
                select s.LookupValue == i.OriginalSystemLookupValue ?
                    new LookupValue {
                        DisplayText = _institutionItem.LookupText,
                        Value = _institutionItem.LookupValue
                    }
                :   new LookupValue {
                        DisplayText = _systemItem.LookupText,
                        Value = _systemItem.LookupValue
                    }
               );
```

Answer (score 3):

Is `_values` a `List<LookupValue>` which is empty to start with? If so, that look might look like this:

```
_values = (from x in _systemData
           from y in _institutionData
           let item = x.LookupValue == y.OriginalSystemLookupValue ? x : y
           select new LookupValue { DisplayText = item.LookupText,
                                    Value = item.LookupValue })
          .ToList();
```

That assumes that `_systemItem` and `_institutionItem` are the same type. If they're unrelated types, you might want to give them a common interface that defines `LookupText` and `LookupValue` (or even a `ToLookupValue` method) and then cast one of the operands in the conditional operator to the interface. For example:

```
_values = (from x in _systemData
           from y in _institutionData
           let item = x.LookupValue == y.OriginalSystemLookupValue
                      ? (ILookupSource) x : y
           select item.ToLookupValue())
          .ToList();
```

Comment: I would not assume that those are the same types.

Comment: I agree, it doesn't seem likely. That would make too much sense.

Comment: @SLaks: I was editing to mention that :) If they're not the same type, I think it's worth encapsulating what they have in common in an interface.

Comment: @gevjen: And can you put a common interface on them, as I suggested?

Comment: I dont know if this information helps, but Im using EF and RiaService. this code is being place into a class that is implemening ILookupService. i am filling these two objects through two calls to these entities. System information fills the system object and vise versa..so for example, if i have a state lookup group and all 50 states as values and for example an institution wants Washington just as Wash we would use Wash from institution entity and not Washington from system entity.so im hoping that i dont have to get into creating other interfaces.unless thats my only option.thanks for help!

Comment: @gevjen: You don't *have* to create interfaces, but in my view it makes the code cleaner.